# Infinite Harmonic Progression

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions, geometric-progressions

Today, I was handing a lot with Progressions. 
It came to my mind that there are infinite AP and GP. 
for example :- 
An Arithmetic Progression with First term 2 and common difference 5 looks like the following :- 
2,7,12,17 ...... and it bursts to infinity

Similarly, An Geometric Progression with First term 2 and common ratio 5 looks like the following :- 
2,10,50,250.... and this also burst to infinity 
*(By infinity, I mean all positive integers)*

**But then what about Harmonic Progressions, do they also bursts to infinity?**

**I think that there doesn't exists any infinite Harmonic Progression containing all positive integers.**

*(Insight is that it's the reciprocal of Arithmetic Progression)*

**But How do I prove it?**

*(I tried a lot but couldn't get a final result.)*

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)

Comment: I know about Harmonic Progression! My intention is to prove if there is any infinite Harmonic Progression containing all postive integers.